# Error code 18 or 22 while creating files through fileSystem API in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I've written below code to create a new file through fileSystem API which came up in HTML5:

```
var mywindow = window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

mywindow(window.TEMPORARY, 5 * 1024 * 1024, getFile, handleError);

function getFile(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("example.txt", { create: true }, fileOpened, handleError);
}

function fileOpened(fileEntry) {
    console.log("File opened!");
    fileEntry.createWriter(writeToFile, handleError);

}

function writeToFile(fileWriter) {
    fileWriter.onwriteend = function() { alert('Success'); };
    fileWriter.onerror = function() { alert('Failed'); };
    fileWriter.write(new Blob(['Hello world'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
    }


function handleError(error) {
console.log('an error has occured ' + error.code);
}
```

Trying to create `example.txt` file results in `handleError` method getting called with error code 18. Am I missing something in the code?

Google chrome version: 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

**Update 1**: Launching Google chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` argument results in same error code 18.

**Update 2**:  When I browser the html file directly from disk then it results in error code 18 but when I host the same html file inside a website in IIS the error code changes to 22.

Comment: Your browser is enforcing a security policy, you can try opening Google Chrome with the flag --alow-file-access-from-files for example `.\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be helping. I still get same error after launching chrome with this additional parameter.

Comment: and you're reading a local file? (the url is `file://....`)

Comment: No. As you can see in the code snippet that I'm trying to open a file named `example.txt` using `fileSystem.root.getFile` API. This API creates a file if it is not already present. I'm trying to use fileSystem API feature of HTML5 for the first time on my computer so it should create a new file in my case. The actual directory path where `example.txt` will get created is controlled by the browser I believe. I don't think that I can give a random file path on my hard disk e.g. `D:\example.txt` to be opened by fileSystem APIs of HTML5 as these API function under a sand-boxed environment.

Comment: @Purefan I notice one more thing. When I browser the html file directly from disk then it results in error code 18 but when I host the same html file inside a website in IIS the error code changes to 22.

Comment: Chromium error -18 is "// Not enough room left on the disk. NET_ERROR(FILE_NO_SPACE, -18)".  What happens if you go to HTML5 local storage test pages in the browser?

Comment: "Non-standard
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future." -- scary warning at Mozilla Foundation

Comment: I think you're trying a risky way of saving a file to disk, it would be very dangerous if websites could create files in the hard drive without the user consent, and if user consent is not a problem then downloading a file should be enough.

Comment: Very true! I'm just trying to learn how it all worked. I'm not doing it for production use as it is already a deprecated/non-standard feature as per HTML team.